# Ruby: Libusb, one USB Device, two input endpoints = difficulties

Tags: ruby, libusb

I'd like to read out an USB Device in Ruby with libusb, which has two endpoints for input, once 0x81, which is in fact a Midi input Connector, and 0x82, which is the HID of this particular device (where the midi input is built in).

The problem is: Libusb responds with an Timeout, if the Endpoint 0x81 (Midi) is not being fed with data through the Midi input. So in order to fetch data simultaneously also from Endpoint 0x82 (HID), i need a construction like

```
begin  
  data = @handle.bulk_transfer(:endpoint=>0x81, :dataIn=>512, :timeout=>20) 

 rescue  
  data2 = @handle.bulk_transfer(:endpoint=>0x82, :dataIn=>512, :timeout=>20)
end
```

But this doesn't work at all, because i won't get any updated data from the HID-Endpoint (0x82), unless the Midi-Endpoint also receives data .

Endpoint 0x82 doesn't generate an timeout when asking for data, but the transmitted Data doesn't change by any action on the HID. Without previously calling Endpoint 0x81 at least the HID works fine.

Is there anything additional that i should tell libusb before accessing another endpoint, after a timeout occurs? According to Lsusb the device itself only accepts bulk transfers on those endpoints.

Comment: It kind of sounds like the firmware of this device is just broken or at least not designed for your use case so there is nothing you can do to fix it using libusb.  You're trying to read data from the HID endpoint, but that only works if the device receives data via its MIDI (non-USB) interface, and then the computer reads that data from the MIDI endpoint (0x81)?  Maybe the HID data represents foot pedals or something else that modifies the music, and the firmware designer didn't think it was important to report changes to that if there is no music?

Comment: Not totally. The Endpoint 0x82 / HID (a control panel with various knobs and displays) works fine, as long as the endpoint 0x81 (Midi) isn't previously called. It i surely an programming error at my point, because under Windows and in combination with the device specific driver it just works fine. 

It -might- be the case, that i have to tell the device to transfer data from endpoint 0x81 (Midi), regardless, if any data of any size is received through the Midi interface, because an Endpoint that generates Timeouts is for my rather unusual.

Comment: "isn't previously called" is confusing to me... that makes it sounds like the traffic on endpoint 0x81 actually breaks other features of the device which brings us back to a firmware bug.  But since you have code that works for you on Windows, it would be good to use a USB protocol analyzer to see exactly what it does, and then do the exact same thing on Linux as a starting point.  Also, of course, note that if you are in a blocking libusb function that is reading data from one input, then no other part of your code will be running until that function returns.

Comment: And you might want to access libusb directly using C, just to rule out bugs in whatever Ruby wrapper layer you are using.

Comment: Yep, i've analyzed the Protocol (in fact the entire device) of this machine utilizing an USB Sniffer under Windows, but i cannot see anything special that is going on. Only that the Analyzer also shows only capture activity when the builtin Midi interface receives data, but it is all standard "bulk or interrupt transfer". Endpoint 0x82 shows the usual and well known activity.

Comment: Got it working, but not exactly as it should be. I have to ask Endpoint 0x82 to deliver Data for at least three times after Ruby rescues from a timeout of Endpoint 0x81. I assume that EP 0x81 should be handled rather with an interrupt transfer, but Libusb doesn't like that (responds with an I/O-Error). 

Lsusb also doesn't show an Interrupt capability on EP 0x81, only bulk. So in theory the device itself doesn't seem to "recover" fast enough when a bulk transfer on EP 0x81 is initiated and no data can be delivered. Still wondering how this is managed in Windows.